# A generalised Young integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, rough-paths

Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. The *pointwise Holder exponent* $H_f (x)$ of $f$ at $x \in [0, 1]$ is defined to be

$$H_f (x) := \sup \left \{ \alpha \in [0, 1] \, \big |\,  \limsup_{y \to x} \frac{|f(y) - f(x)|}{|y - x|^\alpha} < \infty \right \}$$

**Question:** Suppose $f, g$ are continuous functions such that for all $x \in [0, 1]$, we have $H_f (x) + H_g (x) > 1$. Does the integral $\int_0^1 f \, dg$ exist as a Riemann-Stiltjes integral?

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/17442508.2019.1602130

Comment: That looks tasty… @user479223

Comment: It is delicious.